# How do I scrape/query a torrent tracker for torrents named similarly?

Tags: bittorrent

How do I scrape for torrents of a certain file-name? I've read through the http bittorrent tracker spec, but you seem to only be able to query files based on their specific info name.

Is there no way to query for a group of files, or based on file/torrent name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trackers do not know anything about torrent contents, they only track torrents based on the infohashes.

.torrent file indexing (what torrent sites do) and obtaining peer lists (what trackers do) are separate concerns.